# Fast randomly sample a varied number of ones by row from one hot encoded matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, random

I have a one hot encoded `M x N` matrix, `A`, with the following properties:

- 1 or more columns in each row can eq 1
- Every column in the matrix will have exactly one cell with a value of one (all other cells will be zero)
- `M` << `N`

I also an `M x 1` array, `B`, that contains integers (i.e. number of random samples I want to select). Each cell of `B` has the following property:

- `B[i]` <= `np.sum(M[i])`

I’m looking for the most efficient way to randomly sample a subset of the ones in each row of `A`. The number of samples returned for each row is given by the the integer values in the corresponding cells of `B`. The output will be an `M x N` matrix, let's call it `C`,  where `B == np.sum(C, axis=1)`

Example

```
A = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], 
              [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], 
              [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
B = np.array([1, 3, 2])
```

A valid output of running this algorithm would be

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Another possible output would be

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], 
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], 
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Looking for the ability to generate `X` random samples as fast as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

A = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
              [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
B = np.array([1, 3, 2])

C = np.c_[B, A]

def sample_ones(x):
    indices = np.where(x[1:] == 1)[0]  # indices of 1s
    subset_indices = np.random.choice(a=indices, size=indices.size - x[0], replace=False)  # indices of NON-sampled 1s
    x[subset_indices + 1] = 0  # replace non-sampled 1s with 0s
    return x[1:]

print(np.apply_along_axis(sample_ones, 1, C))
```

Output:

```
[[0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I don't receive any alternative answers in the next week or so, I'll accept.